# Partiton scanning increases if the functions like UPPER is used

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I noticed that the partition scanning increases if we use functions like UPPER in the where clause. Although it is not required to use UPPER, but I wanted to know why it changes the behavior of  partition scanning. It seems like if functions are used, it forces a lot more scanning of the partitions

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SCOPS_DB.TABLE1 
WHERE YEAR =2015 and UPPER(COL1)='COLVAL';
```

**SCANS 18,759 PARTITIONS**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SCOPS_DB.TABLE1 
WHERE YEAR =2015 and COL1='COLVAL';
```

**SCANS 1 PARTITION**

Thanks
Rajib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake stores metadata about each column in a metadata services layer including: "The range of values for each of the columns in the micro-partition". To me, this is like having an index on each column pointing to the the corresponding micro-partitions in your table.

In your example, this range of values stored in the metadata layer for `COL1` is stored it its raw form (probably a mix of upper and lower case). This means when you apply a function to the column, the metadata services layer cannot be used as an "index" to fetch the micro-partitions for the range of rows you need.

If you need to, you can create a cluster key to the column which does apply a function. In which case it'll be used when you apply that same function as a predicate.